# SwiftUI Image render different from UIImage (PDF, Vectoriel)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am wondering why is there a difference in rendering between `SwiftUI.Image` and `UIKit.UIImage` for vectoriel image (PDF)?

UIKit:

[image]

SwiftUI:

[image]

Thanks for any help here!

Things I already tried or done:

- `.renderingMode(.template)` manually in addition of setting it in `.xassets`
- `.interpolation(.high)`, `.interpolation(.none)` -> both case looks bad.

This is a workaround here for peeps that don't look for a SwiftUI solution in particular -> [Why do PDFs resized in SwiftUI getting sharp edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164005/why-do-pdfs-resized-in-swiftui-getting-sharp-edges?rq=1)