# Blurry SVG render when using HeroIcons in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, svg, swiftui, blurry

I am using HeroIcons (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons) in my iOS app. I have added all SVG files into Resource bundle and able to render the SVG using SwiftUI.

But the rendered icon looks blurry

[image: blurry]

This is the SVG configuration

[image]

And this is the `SwiftUI` code snippet to display the icon

[image]

Any SVG export can help me with this?

Answer (score 26):

Just select the “Preserve vector data” option in the image configuration, that should fix your issue.

Comment: I had some problematic `SVG` assets that would render blurry - I can confirm that this works. So make sure "`Preserver Vector Data`" is selected in the `Attribute Inspector` for the image resource. This _should_ make sure that your asset is crisp, clear and scales.

Comment: I have this `Preserver Vector Data` enabled but it still looks blurry.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Jus setting the proper options on the image in the asset catalog (preserve vector data, single scale) definitely works, and contrary to other comments, is not an issue with Image.
This works fine:
```
        Image("adjustments").resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: For me, it is blurry on iOS 14 simulator and sharp on iOS 15 simulator when using SwiftUI's `Image("name")`

Comment: I had the same issue with blurry on one simulator and sharp on another. The fix was to click Device>Erase all Contents and Settings on the simulator's menu, which forced a new build onto there with all new files and now it looks good.

Comment: Thanks for that, this is correct answer!

Comment: Rather than blurry, my SVGs were very jagged - setting 'preserve vector data' on the assets' config fixed this too.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe there is something wrong with `Image`'s rendering mechanism for `SVG`.

Following this question, I have adopted using `UIImageView` + `UIViewRepresentable` to render `SVG` and it works great.

You can take a look a similar implementation of a SwiftuI compatible `UIImageView` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178828/452115

Answer (score 0):

If the suggestion from David doesn't work, this might work then:

```
Image(uiImage: .init(named: "HeroIcons/outline/adjustments", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil))
       .resizable()
       ...
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to check that out. I wonder if this is directly correlated to the asset option, allowing one to override it. It's still easier to handle this in the asset catalog, as you can select multiple SVGs and set the option for all of them at once.

Comment: I've seen this problem happening when `SwiftUI.Image` was used directly to create an image (I believe it was on iOS 13), and using `UIImage` instead fixed the blurring issue for me.